# Google Directions API sum of steps duration inconsistent with total leg duration

Tags: google-api, google-api-python-client, google-directions-api

I'm using the Directions API with 'transit' mode and as a sanity check I compare the total distance and duration of one (there is only one) leg and the sum of its steps. I get that the distances add up, but the duration does not, given that I have some transit mode of transport (i.e. not just walking). Below illustrates the check:

```
from = (59.294420, 18.102213) 
to = (59.297550, 18.087510)
departure_time = 1629957600
response = make_request(from, to, departure_time, 'transit', api_key, ...)

leg = response['routes'][0]['legs'][0]
total_distance_meters = leg['distance']['value']
total_travel_time_seconds = leg['duration']['value']

acc_distance = 0
acc_duration = 0
for i_step, step in enumerate(leg['steps']):
    print(f"step {i_step+1}, distance={step['distance']['text']}, travel time={step['duration']['text']}, mode={step['travel_mode']}")
    acc_distance += step['distance']['value']
    acc_duration += step['duration']['value']
print(f"Sanity check: Total distance={total_distance_meters}, accumulated distance={acc_distance}")
print(f"Sanity check: Total duration={total_travel_time_seconds}, accumulated duration={acc_duration}")

# --> Output:
# step 1, distance=68 m, travel time=1 min, mode=WALKING
# step 2, distance=0.8 km, travel time=2 mins, mode=TRANSIT
# step 3, distance=0.4 km, travel time=5 mins, mode=WALKING
# Sanity check: Total distance=1268, accumulated distance=1268
# Sanity check: Total duration=478, accumulated duration=477
```

If I give an origin-destination pair with a single step of walking only, the durations are equal. With an origin-destination pair of longer distance and more steps, I get larger discrepancy between the total and accumulated numbers.

Is there some 'hidden' duration somewhere, or am I missing something?

Comment: You should file a bug in the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/components/188841) as this is most likely a data issue and not a programming issue.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a data issue to be addressed with Google.